# How to display the value of return level

Tags: r

I have plot the return level plot by using the following coding in R.

```
data(ftcanmax)
fit <- gev.fit(ftcanmax[,"Prec"])
return.level(fit)
```

How to display the value of return level for corresponding return period? For example, when return period is 10, what is the value of return value?

Comment: Presumably this comes from a package. It is common courtesy to name the package or include code that would load the package. That might also make the data available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is the example from package extRemes ?return.level:

```
library(extRemes)
#...code
rets<-return.level(fit)
rets$return.level[rets$return.period==10]
#[1] 281.459
```

That only is possible if the 'rperiods' argument to `return.level` includes the period of interest ... which it does for 10 in the default case. So for a non-defautl period, this should suffice:

```
>  return.level(fit ,rperiod=12)$return.level
[1] 296.796
```